# Is there a category for pre-smooth spacetime geometry?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics

I start with an Euclidean space. 
I drop global symmetry and I get a Riemannian manifold. 
I drop symmetry (isotropy) in the tangent space and I get a Finsler manifold. 
I drop differentiability and I get a metric space.

What happens if I start with Minkowski's spacetime?
I drop global symmetry and I get a pseudo-Riemannian manifold. 
Can I drop symmetry of the tangent spaces? (Question) 
Can I drop differentiability? (Main question)

Has anyone studied categories analog to that of metric spaces or Finsler manifolds, but including a notion of causality/order/passage of time?

Comment: I have no knowledge about this, but I think there is also a Finsler approach for Lorentzian geometry, because people doing general relativity using Finsler spacetimes

Comment: I'm sure others will be able to give a more precise reference, but I seem to recall that a causal structure on a smooth manifold is equivalent to specifying a conformal structure.  I'm not sure how much differentiability is required, though: I suspect smoothness might be too strong.  There is also a discrete approach to quantum gravity based on the notion of causal sets, in which one does not even have a (topologucal) manifold.

Comment: I've briefly heard about the concept of a "Causal Space". but I do not know enough about it to know if this is what you are asking. I believe the paper is called "On the structure of causal spaces," however, so feel free to take a look.

Comment: Are you looking for something like a directed topological space?  If so, you could start at http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/directed+topological+space and follow the references.
